# migrating python 2.7 and :. Print statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am interested in migrating my code to python 3 and the only thing that I am using that causes some problems is the print statement. I would like users of both python 2.7 and version 3 to be able to use my code.

At the moment, I am getting errors on lines which use string concatenation like:

```
print 'im shape ' + str(im.data.shape)
```

I know I am supposed to use the print function and I think that would work on both 2.7 and 3.x but is there a way to handle this string concatenation in a way that would work on both 2.7 and 3.x versions of python?

Comment: Have you tried? I have no problem with str concatenation inside the print function.

Comment: i did. I was getting a syntax error. Perhaps something else was wrong. I will investigate more. Thanks!

Comment: If you get a SyntaxError, *that* is what you should be asking. And show the actual code + the backtrace from the error.

Comment: What do you mean by `:.` in the question title?

Comment: @Evert You did not a syntax error, maybe because using python 2.7? Here what I get with a similar case: http://ideone.com/nK18io

Comment: Use `from __future__ import print_function` at the start of your script and Python 2.7 will use `print` as it is in Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem at all with simply wrapping this in parentheses: that will work in both 2.7 and 3.x:

```
print('im shape ' + str(im.data.shape))
```

However, you shouldn't be doing concatenation like that anyway. Use one of the string substitution methods:

```
print('im shape {}'.format(im.data.shape))
```

Comment: true, print is the least problem when writing code portable between the pythons ;)

Comment: @daniel-Roseman please mention or point to why string substitution should be used. Rama's answer is more direct but you offer a hint of potential improved guidance. Cheers! :-).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the automated translation tools provided by the 3.x python distribution, the print statements will be automatically transformed in print function calls.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

And print concatenation works perfectly in python 3

```
print ('im shape ' + str(im.data.shape))
```